# Disable action button in R facing problem for multiple inputs

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, action-button

Hi i am building an R code as follow to have an shiny app

```
ui = fluidPage(
  
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::inlineCSS(appCSS),
  shinyFeedback::useShinyFeedback(),
  titlePanel("Predicting concrete strength",""),
  numericInput("CEM","Cement (kg)",""),
  numericInput("Water","Water (kg)",""),
  numericInput("PFA","Flyash (kg)",""),
  actionButton("submit", "Get the results", class = "btn-primary"),
  textOutput("class"),
  textOutput("class_prob")
  )
```

and the server code is

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
   inputsValues = reactiveValues(inputs = NULL)
  
## to disable action button until all inputs are given
   observe({
     
     if(input$CEM!="" && input$Water!= "" && input$PFA!=""){
       shinyjs::enable("submit")
     } else {
       shinyjs::disable("submit")
     }
   })
   # putting some feedback if inputs are wrongly given
  observeEvent(input$submit,{
    
    cem_con<- (as.numeric(input$CEM) > 163 & as.numeric(input$CEM) < 3307)
    shinyFeedback::feedbackDanger("CEM", !cem_con  , " abc")
    wat_con<- (as.numeric(input$Water) > 131 & as.numeric(input$Water) < 1640)
    shinyFeedback::feedbackDanger("Water",!wat_con  , "abc")
    pfa_con<-(as.numeric(input$PFA) > 55 & as.numeric(input$PFA) < 1617)
    shinyFeedback::feedbackDanger("PFA", !pfa_con, "abc")
    req(cem_con,wat_con)
    inputsValues$inputs<-c("CEM"=input$CEM,"Water"=input$Water,"PFA"=input$PFA)
    inputsValues$inputs<-as.numeric(inputsValues$inputs)
  })
  
  output$class_prob<- renderText(inputsValues$inputs)
  output$class <- renderText(sum(inputsValues$inputs))
  
}
```

and when I run the app using

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

its stops and give the following error

*Listening on http://126.0.0.1:3739
Warning: Error in enable: could not find function "enable"
[No stack trace available]*

Comment: what about attaching `shinyjs` ? or change to `shinyjs::enable("submit")` and `shinyjs::disable("submit")`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It did work but does not fulfil my objective 
and see I change the code again now it is not working
actually, I want to take action button to be enabled only when all inputs are given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for missing value, you could use `is.na()` as shown below.

```
observe({
    if (is.na(input$CEM) | is.na(input$Water) | is.na(input$PFA) ) {
      shinyjs::disable("submit")
    } else {
      shinyjs::enable("submit")
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it is working now can you please elaborate me why the error was coming, Thanks and regards

Comment: You have set the initial value to be missing.  `is.na()` is just checking if the initial value is still missing.  Please try `?is.na()` in the console of RStudio for further information.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I am curious that why we cant specify the missing value as  "" in R ?